# In Tastypie with nested resources, for a given url, what is the best way to get the view function name?

Tags: django, tastypie

I can get the view name through the following steps

1. Get the View name of the child resource

   ```
   from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

   resolve(/api/v1/parent/child).view_name
   api_get_children
   ```
2. Look for view name the prepend_urls() under the parent resource. I
   will see something like

   ```
   url(
       r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/children%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
       self.wrap_view('get_children'), 
       name="api_get_children"
   )
   ```
3. Search for the function definition

   ```
   def get_children
   ```

Is there a method to get the function name in one step?